# Resolution issues with Windows Phone apps?

Tags: css, windows, html, windows-phone, scaling

I'm building a Windows Universal App, and at the moment, I'm making the Windows Phone app. I'm debugging using a Nokia Lumia 520 which has a 480px * 800px display.

Because I'm using HTML5 & Javascript instead of XAML to build the app, I'm worried that it might look bad on a 1920*1080 Windows Phone or another Windows Phone with higher resolution. Because I have no way to test this theory, how can I be sure that all Windows Phone's will display my app correctly?

Comment: Nokia remote device access will make it possible to test on a screen with a higher resolution

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio gives you a lot of Windows Phone emulators all with different device and screen sizes . In Visual Studio you can select target device on the "Debug" button.

[image: Screenshot]